# Firebase dynamic link fallback url doesn't work with custom play store listing

Tags: firebase, google-play-console, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a custom plays store listing and created a campaign for my android app, the url is taking me to the new custom listing page, but when I add same link in firebase dynamic link fall back url for app not installed case it is taking me to old listing page.